# Running "eas build --local" in GitHub Action, uploading to GitHub Releases, and generating QR code

Tags: react-native, expo, github-actions

I have an Expo project, and I'm trying to set up a GitHub Actions workflow to streamline the build process. Specifically, I want to achieve the following steps in my workflow:

- Run `eas build --local` to build my Expo app locally.
- Upload the built apps (e.g., Android and iOS) to GitHub Releases.
- Generate a QR code for the app, which can be scanned using Expo Go.

I am trying to avoid using `eas build --auto` because it's not free.

I've managed to create individual steps for building locally as shown below:

```yaml
jobs: 
  build_android:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' || github.event_name == 'push'
    name: Setup and Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name:  Setup Workflow
        uses: ./.github/actions/setup

      - name:  Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
          cache: pnpm
      - name:  Install dependencies
        run: pnpm install
     
      - name:  Setup EAS
        uses: expo/expo-github-action@v8
        with:
          eas-version: latest
          token: ${{ secrets.EXPO_TOKEN }}

      - name:  Build android app
        run: |
              eas build --local \
              --non-interactive \
              --output=./app-build \
              --platform=android 
  
      - name:  Build ios app
        run: |
              eas build --local \
              --non-interactive \
              --output=./app-build \
              --platform=ios
```

How can I now get these individual builds on GitHub releases and then expose an Expo URL for testing?

Comment: Yes, but I ended up using EAS instead. So basically I setup develop and production tracks. The development track is a dev build and I can now push updates directly to that using Over The Air updates using "eas update", When I want to push to production ( Playstore/ testflight ), I run eas build with autosubmit. 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For release management you can add following content to your yml file

```
  - name: Publish update
    id: generating_apk
    run: eas build --profile preview --platform android --non-interactive --local --output=./app-release.apk

  - name: Create Release
    id: create_release
    uses: actions/create-release@v1
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    with:
      tag_name: ${{ github.run_number }}
      release_name: Release ${{ github.run_number }}
      prerelease: true

  - name: Upload Release Asset
    id: upload-release-asset 
    uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    with:
      upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }} # This pulls from the CREATE RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
      asset_path: ./app-release.apk
      asset_name: app-release.apk
      asset_content_type: application/vnd.android.package-archive
```

For generating qr code you can use following action

```
- name: Generating QR code
  id: generating_qr_code
  uses: kentaro-m/qr-code-commenter-action@v0.1.2
  with: 
    repo-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
    content: https://github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/<GITHUB_REPO_NAME>/releases/download/${{ github.run_number }}/app-release.apk
    comment: |
      :lock: This is a QR code for access to the preview website.:iphone: Scan a code with your device.{qrcode}
```

Modify content url according to your github username and project repo name.

Hope this will help